# turn on/off the method follow props in React

Tags: reactjs

I have developed a Component clickable.

and I want to make it disabled sometimes.

```
const MyComponent = ({disabled}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={!disabled&&()=>console.log("CLICKED")}>btn</button>
  )
}

const MyApp = () => {
  return (
    <MyComponent disabled={true} />
  )
}
```

but it doesn't work.

and I have one solution what I don't want to use with.

```
const MyComponent = ({disabled}) => {
  function handleClick(){
    if(!disabled){
      console.log("CLICCKED");
    }
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>btn</button>
  )
}
```

Is there any solution better than what I found?

Comment: Just put the !disabled into the button's onClick callback body

Comment: onClick={() => !disabled && console.log("clicked")}

Comment: @AmirAleahmad Thank you so much, I've just missed a simple thing. Why don't you answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use simple `disabled` property of `button`,

```
<button onClick={()=>console.log("CLICKED")} disabled={disabled}>btn</button>
```

Comment: oh, I am sorry, that is just an example. my real code has not `<button />`

Comment: In that case you need to post your actual code and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I already found what I want :)